# how to hatch turtles that face closest neighbor of agentset doing the hatching

Tags: indexing, distance, netlogo, closest, closest-points

I currently have one agentset(ports) hatching another agentset(ships). 
The idea is to have the ships face the closest port to their current location.

`[let target min-one-of ports [distance myself] 
 face target]`.

Unfortunately this makes the ships face their current location since they are being hatched at a given port. If there is no way to exclude the port they hatch on- I have an index of the locations(ports) and could potentially set the target as the following item in the index however I am not sure how I would accomplish this. any suggestions?

full code example

```
breed [ships ship]
breed[ports port]

to setup 

   let index 0  
 create-ports 3 
 [ let loc item index [ [459 -324] [670 -233] [677 -356] ]      
   setxy (item 0 loc) (item 1 loc) 
   set index index + 1  
   set shape "circle" 
   set size 5
   set color red - 1]    

 ask ports
 [ hatch-ships 1 
 [ set size 10
   set color red
   pen-down  
   set pen-size 1
   let target min-one-of other ports [distance myself]   
   face target] ]

 reset-ticks 
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign the who value of hatching port to the ship as their current port and define their target port as the closes port which is not the current port.

```
breed [ships ship]
breed[ports port]
ships-own [currentPort targetPort]
to setup 
clear-all
   let index 0  
 create-ports 3 
 [
 ; let loc item index [ [459 -324] [670 -233] [677 -356] ]      

 let loc item index [ [4 -4] [ 9 5] [ -11 11] ] 
   setxy (item 0 loc) (item 1 loc) 
   set index index + 1  
   set shape "circle" 
   set size 5
   set color red - 1]    

 ask ports
 [ 


   let s who
   set label ( word S "    Port    "  s )
   hatch-ships 1 

 [ set currentPort s
   set shape "sailboat side"
   set size 10
   set color red
   pen-down  
   set pen-size 1
   Set targetPort min-one-of ports with [ who != s] [distance myself]   
   set heading towards targetport
   set label (word "target " targetport)

   ] ]

 reset-ticks 
end
```

[image]

Comment: Im also attempting to make the ships move towards the targetPort and once they arrive, move on to the next targetPort. What i have so far although its not working correctly: 
`ask ships  
 [ if distance target-port = 0
 [ set target-port min-one-of ports with [who != myself] [distance myself]
   face target-port ]
  ifelse distance target-port < 1
 [ move-to target-port ]
 [ fd 1 ] 
 ]`
I would also like to have the ships stop moving once they've met the end of the path. (i.e port 0 or 2). Thanks again

Comment: @mowgly please open a new question. that's the format here on Stack Overflow — one question at a time. (you can link back to this one for context.)

Comment: @SethTisue thanks for the clarification, I'm fairly new at using Stack Overflow.